# Change several elements using PHP

Tags: php, replace

I have this php code

```
$url="hello/f/";
$html="<div class="menu" style='min-height:200px;'>
            <ul class="null">
                <li>
                    <a class=' javalink' href='Index'>Home</a>  
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class=' javalink' href='100'>A 100</a>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class=' javalink' href='150'>B 150</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>";
```

is it possible to replace every `<a>` with class javalink to `<a>` with `$url+old href`
for example

```
<a class=' javalink' href='550c'>E 550c</a>
```

changes to

```
<a href='".$url."550c'>E 550c</a>
```

Comment: Simple notepad ++(or any editor with search->replace_all function ) ctrl + F search for href=' replace with href='".$url." I dont think you need any extra coding into that

Comment: No, you don't understand my question. This code is not constant and changes for every page both $url and $html.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Such as `str_replace` ?

Comment: I think str_replace  only works if every href has the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$url="hello/f/";
$html="<div class='menu' style='min-height:200px;'>
        <ul class='null'>
            <li>
                <a class=' javalink' href='Index'>Home</a>  
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class=' javalink' href='100'>A 100</a>   
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class=' javalink' href='150'>B 150</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>";

print preg_replace("/\<a class\=' javalink' href='(\w+)'\>([\w\s]+)\<\/a\>/im", "<a href='".$url."$1'>$2</a>", $html);
```

Outputs

```
<div class='menu' style='min-height:200px;'>
    <ul class='null'>
        <li>
            <a href='hello/f/Index'>Home</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='hello/f/100'>A 100</a>   
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='hello/f/150'>B 150</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Note: You might have change the regex based on your values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want old href in all `<a>`  tag. If this is your problem then you need to store old url into some variable such as SESSION or COOKIES and then use it.